# how to get network interfaces in linux of my docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, network-interface

i launch some docker nginx containers liket that :

```
docker run --rm -d nginx
docker run --rm -d nginx
docker run --rm -d nginx
```

then i get the ip adresses of my containers, by doing..

```
docker inspect 5d3 | grep IPAd
it gives me ip address : 172.17.0.2
```

```
docker inspect 6r8 | grep IPAd
it gives me ip address : 172.17.0.3
```

```
docker inspect 7h9 | grep IPAd
it gives me ip address : 172.17.0.4
```

My question is : is there a linux command to see my network interfaces ?
I mean.. : 172.17.0.2 + 172.17.0.3 + 172.17.0.4

Thanks by advance.

Comment: that feels very strange. It sounds like you should go the other way around: define a container network, and start three disitinct containers with distinctive assigned addresses in that.